# NestJS Passport Linkedin Strategy

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I have a NestJS application with a JwtStrategy defined. Now what I want is include a LinkedIn Strategy as well. Can somebody explain to me how this can be achieved? Currently I use my FE Angular application to do things like redirecting and exchanging the code for an accessToken. Since storing my clientId, secret and other stuff is not really save I would like to move this to my api side (NestJS app).

Answer (score 1):

I hate to link over to an article or code, as this is a great question, so I'll provide the resources at the bottom of the answer. For the most part, this can be achieved as you did your JWTStrategy, you'll find a passport strategy you want to use (LinkedIn OAuth for example), you write your LinkedIn strategy, determine the best way to figure out if the user already exists in your system (email is usually a good one), and save their LinkedIn token with them. From there, you'll create a custom guard that checks for `req.isAuthenticated()` and returns if they are or are not. You'll probably also need a serialization class that handles the serializing and deserializing of the OAuth response for passport. And lastly, if you are working with OAuth, you'll probably be dealing with sessions, so you'll probably need the `express-session` package, and you'll probably want to add in Redis for keeping the session tokens.

[Article written by John about MVC Sessions](https://dev.to/nestjs/authentication-and-sessions-for-mvc-apps-with-nestjs-55a4)

[Sample code for Passport with OAuth](https://github.com/johnbiundo/mvc-sessions)